# empty "lsmod | grep loop"

Tags: mount, modprobe

I am trying to mount an ISO image

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/myiso
$ sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso /mnt/uiso
```

The error message says

```
mount: /mnt/uiso: failed to setup loop device for /home/sebas/isos/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso.
```

As sugested in other entries here, I try

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep loop
```

and get an empty output

The problem is that the command

```
$ sudo modprobe loop
```

... produces nothing, as "lsmod" still is empty

How can I fix that ?
My system is a Ubuntu 18.04.2 :

```
sag@T60ubuntu:/mnt$ uname -r
4.15.0-51-generic
```

Comment: Looks like "loop" driver is not a loadable module but compiled in kernel. So why my "mount" is failing ?

Comment: you can edit your question to add this. people won't read coments when reading this question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `mount: /mnt/uiso: failed to setup loop device for /home/sebas/isos/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso` does not seem to agree with your mount point creation `sudo mkdir /mnt/myiso`

You should either change the mount point to `uiso` or fix the mount command to point to `/mnt/myiso`:

`sudo mount /home/sebas/isos/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso /mnt/myiso -o loop`

Comment: no, the mkdir was ok, i got a typo when writing here. the problem was CRC, as i just said here - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there was a CRC problem with the ISO file.

I downloaded it again and verified as Ubuntu indicates ...

```
echo "ea6ccb5b57813908c006f42f7ac8eaa4fc603883a2d07876cf9ed74610ba2f53 *ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso" | sha256sum --check
```

... and now it mounts ok.

Strange there was no error message indicating the source of problem.
Thanks anyway.