# Mount does not work only in shell script, loop device

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, scripts

I have a script that includes the line:

```bsh
sudo mount -o loop ./ubuntu.iso ./mount
```

In interactive shell (bash), this works totally fine. If I run the script, the command fails with:

```
mount: ./mount: failed to setup loop device for ubuntu.iso.
```

This is running in WSL2, but as the command works in the interactive shell, I would *think* it's not related.

Comment: Related: [empty “lsmod | grep loop”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150312/empty-lsmod-grep-loop)

Comment: At the prompt in WSL, please run the command `uname -a` and then add the results of that command to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue in question was related to an incorrect filename.

So when specifying the mount, if the real filename is ubuntuubuntu.iso but I give the command as `sudo mount -o loop ./ubuntu.iso ./mount`, it will give me the error specified above due to using the wrong filename for the iso.

The solution here was to use the correct filename and enter the command as `sudo mount -o loop ./ubuntuubuntu.iso ./mount`

Comment: Please add some details to your answer so it get a little bit more helpful to others reading your question.